# Problem reading separated strings at every line and saving info in a stack

Tags: c++, buffer

I have to save every line in a different stack. And for every line I need to separate the data (that is already divided by the space ('_') char).

The input comes like this:

```
n //n being the size of a vector that saves every stack.
DATA1 DATA2 DATA3
DATA4 DATA5
DATA6
```

I came out with something like this:

```
vector<stack<string>> library;
string line;
int n;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n and getline(cin, line); ++i)
{
    stack<string> books;
    while (getline(cin, line, ' '))
    {
        books.push(line);
    }
    library[i] = books;
}

//code to print and make sure every stack has elements:
for (int i = 0; i < library.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "[" << i << "] -> ";
    while (not library[i].empty())
    {
        cout << library[i].top();
        if(library[i].size() > 1) cout << ", ";
        library[i].pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And I end up with the following output (endl/break line included):

```
[0] -> DATA5
DATA6, DATA3
DATA4, DATA2, DATA1
```

**The output should be:**

```
[0] -> DATA3, DATA2, DATA1
[1] -> DATA5, DATA4
[2] -> DATA6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two "levels" of `getline`.  First, read each line into it's own string.  Then put that string into a `stringsteam` so you can then use `getline` or `operator >>` to extract each element from the line.  That would look like

```
vector<stack<string>> library;
string line;
int n;
cin >> n;
// clear newline from buffer
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')
// preallocate stacks
library.reserve(n);
// for each line of data
while (getline(cin, line))
{
    std::stack data;
    std::string element
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    // get each element from the line and add to the stack
    // since it is space seperate no need to use getline(cin, element, ' ')
    while (ss >> element) 
        data.push(element);
    library.push_back(data);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! Also the line "cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')" gives me an error, but I just used cin.ignore().

Comment: @DumbProgrammer What error do you get?  You might need to add `#include <limits>` for it to work.

Comment: With `#include <limits>` works perfectly thank you, I will investigate more about cin.ignore() :D